ASP.NET controller not receiving input
I have some mock web interface. It is supposed to take a user comment and save it to a json file. Then print the contents of the json in the html. However for some reason my controller is unable to receive the commentValue.
<script>
    let userField = document.querySelector("#userComment")
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("SubmitComment")',
        contentType: 'text/plain',
        data: {commentValue : userField.value},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                const lastComment = data[data.length - 1];
                var rowHtml = `
                    <div class="comment-bubble">
                        <div class="comment-value">${lastComment.userComment}</div>
                        <div class="comment-datetime">
                            <div>${lastComment.timeStamp}</div>
                            <div>${lastComment.dateStamp}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`;
                $("#comm").append(rowHtml);
            }
        }
    })
</script>

[HttpPost]
public string SubmitComment(string commentValue)
{
    // Body...

    return "Some String...";
}

I have checked to make sure that the javascript is actually retrieving the commentValue, and checked to see if its being sent in the http request but still I draw blanks.
